# server issues with form submit and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have two issues that i have problem with them and i dont really know where to start looking and how to handle them:

first one is jquery issue...

when i load the page on my computer (local) all appear right:

```
if($('.error',$formId).length) {
            return false;
        }
    else{ 
        $('#btn-submit').fadeOut(200, function() {
              $('#btn-submit').attr("src","images/Site_Images/checkMark.jpg");
              $('#btn-submit').fadeIn(200);
              $('#btn-submit').removeAttr('onmouseover').removeAttr('onmouseout');
        });

         // $formId.trigger('submit');
        }
```

the check mark appear...
[image]

when i load my site in wamp server and remove the comments  // $formId.trigger('submit');

so the form will submit and the **2 issues** occur : ( if i leave the submit line comment out then the pic will be visible )

it has to be something with the form submit.

first is the check mark :

[image]

not appear.

and **second** is after submit. all the form disappear.

how can i solve those issues?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you check your HTML code after the fade is finished..

Comment: i have check it with the debugger and after the img src change and attribute remove, the html element seems fine the img path has changed and the attributes were removed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the "images/Site_Images/checkMark.jpg" file doesn't exist, so you should double check that the file is uploaded using the same directory structure as it was running locally.

Comment: nope the problem not occur when i comment out the submit  '$formId.trigger('submit')' so it has to do with the form submit.